# ngx-bootstrap range datepicker values

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm creating a datatable, which I would like to filter by start and end dates. I'm using ngx-bootstrap range datepicker but I would like to style input field to specific date formats.

The logic is like this:

1. If I chose days in datepicker which are from the same month, I would like to show in input something like: 1 - 3 April 2020.
2. In case I chose days in datepicker which are not frome the same month, I would like to change this format in my input to: 1 January - 3 April 2020, otherwise: 1 - 3 April 2020.
3. The last case is, if both dates are from the same year, I would like to show year only in the second value something like 1 January - 3 April 2020, otherwise: 1 January 1997 - 3 April 2020.

I have tried to set it in bsConfig but this seems to apply to both dates at once, and my question is:
How can I get values and apply different format dates according to my logic?

Is it possible to simply show those formatted values in div, not in input?

Thank you for any response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. Instead of using input, I can use simply div.
I have to add `ngDefaultControl` directive to div, to make sure my datepicker is working with div instead of input. This is my code from HTML:

```
<div
        [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig"
        type="text"
        bsDaterangepicker
        placement="right bottom"
        #dpr="bsDaterangepicker"
        class="datepicker-input"
        readonly
        (bsValueChange)="onDateChange($event)"
        name="fieldName"
        ngDefaultControl
      >
        {{ chosenStartDate }} - {{ chosenEndDate }}
      </div>
```

In this case, I'm able to change format conditionally in my ts file.